# DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple identical st.checkbox widgets with the same generated key

Tags: python, streamlit

I am building stream lit app, I defined two function, sidebar, tab, etc. output of first function is simply a data frame, and output of the second function is chart. I get the error as follows. The error seems to be because of the second function

```
def func():
    option_1 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x1', value=True)
    option_2 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x2')
    option_3 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x3')

    dfall = read()
    dfs = []
    if option_1 :
        dfs.append(dfall[0])
    if option_2 :
        dfs.append(dfall[1])
    if option_3 :
        dfs.append(dfall[2])

    if len(dfs) > 1:

        df = pd.concat(dfs)
       
    elif len(dfs) == 1:
        df = dfs[0]

   do something on df..
   return df

def chart()
   df= func()

   plot the chart 
   return 


with tab1:
    intro()

with tab2:
    func()
    
with tab3:
    chart()
```

The error:

DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple identical st.checkbox widgets with the same generated key.

When a widget is created, it's assigned an internal key based on its structure. Multiple widgets with an identical structure will result in the same internal key, which causes this error.

To fix this error, please pass a unique key argument to st.checkbox.

Comment: In which of your functions are you using `st.checkbox()`? that is where the error is. And is `st.checkbox()` generated in a loop?

Comment: Updated the code with this part. yes this is inside the loop

Comment: If you call `func2()` more than one time then you are likely to get same error. You will have to create keys parameters  for your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. You are having multiple `st.checkbox` widgets maybe in one of your functions with same keys. every check box must have a unique key. If key is not set, the default key is `None` all wiget will have `None` as their key and it will still throw the same error.
Example:

```py
check_one = st.checkbox("Tick", key="check_1") # key must be unique
check_two = st.checkbox("Tick", key="check_2") # key must be unique
```

In your case

```
def func(key1, key2, key3):
    option_1 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x1', key={key1}, value=True)
    option_2 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x2', key={key2})
    option_3 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x3', key={key3})

    dfall = read()
    dfs = []
    if option_1 :
        dfs.append(dfall[0])
    if option_2 :
        dfs.append(dfall[1])
    if option_3 :
        dfs.append(dfall[2])

    if len(dfs) > 1:

        df = pd.concat(dfs)
       
    elif len(dfs) == 1:
        df = dfs[0]

   do something on df..
   return df

def chart():
   df= func(key1="8reh", key2="hdfu03", key3="ryyw32")

   plot the chart 
   return 


with tab1:
    intro()

with tab2:
    func(key1="wwr93", key2="rpt49", key3="rt40")
    
with tab3:
    chart()
```

Comment: Thank you, now I get DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple widgets with the same key='option_1'.

To fix this, please make sure that the key argument is unique for each widget you create.

Comment: I you call `func2()` more than one time then you are likely to get same error.

Comment: And now I get the same error with     start_dt = st.sidebar.date_input('Start date', key='start_dt',value=df['fi_mo'].min())  do you have any idea?

Comment: DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple widgets with the same key='start_dt'.

Comment: I will edit the answer soon to refactor your `func2()`

Comment: I also combined Func2 and func together as one func and put as a input to chart function, will edit the question now.

Comment: I created three key parameters for `func` to pass unique strings `keys` for every argument when calling `func`